# Binary file download using QT

Tags: qt, file, download, translation

I newbie in QT programming  and one of my tools needs a feature to get the audio translation of a text line using google translate api.The easiest solution was to use a special URL Google(*http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="...my string..."*).
Using wget tool a did that by this way :

```
cd google_has_you &&  wget -m -k -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.0.2) Gecko/20121223 Ubuntu/9.25 (jaunty) Firefox/3.8" "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=in+soviet+russia+games+plays+you"
```

and then i renamed downloaded file to test.mp3 to check audio translation

```
teddy@Desktop:~/google_has_you/translate.google.com$ mv * test.mp3
```

My question is how to do it with Qt,that is, how to download a binary file (mp3) from url : http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=" + my text, and then to play downloaded using Phonon.

Comment: Have a look at the QNetworkAccessManager [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) to get an idea of how to tackle the first part of your question. And Qt comes with a mediaplayer example for Phonon. You can use that to figure out the second part.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use QNetworkAccessManager to download the file and then play it by passing the path to the local file to the Phonon media source, or let Phonon stream it.
A code snippet (url is a QUrl) (Everything on the stack because I copied it from a main()):

```
MediaSource src( url );
MediaObject obj;
obj.setCurrentSource( src );
AudioOutput audio( VideoCategory );
Phonon::createPath( &obj, &audio );
obj.play();
```